# tinyMCE instance using ajax works only once

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I have to initialize `tinymce` from the ajax-requested script `get.edit.php`.

`get.edit.php` contains

```
<textarea id="tinymce" rows="8" cols="80" style="width:100%"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#tinymce").tinymce({ 
       /* lot of tinymce data */
    });
</script>
```

and loads data into `<div id="calldata">` in the main script. But after the second request clicking on link_2, link_3, ... I receive only an empty textfield without tinymce. Only reloading of `index.php` helps to correct a situation, but only once besides.

Can someone explain how to solve this problem? Thanx.

Edit: Solution found here: http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?pid=22977 , but not for jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an ajax request that changes the content of your #tinymce div, then you will need to re-initialize the tinymce editor after the changes are loaded.

Maybe add the following to whatever action you call via ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#tinymce").tinymce({ 
       /* lot of tinymce data */
    });
})
```

This will re-initialize it once the page has fully loaded.

Comment: This has already been tried and unfortunately doesn't have the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

add
`$("#tinymce").tinymce({ 
       /* lot of tinymce data */
    });`

in success function in your ajax call. it worked for me.